# How to make Flexbox flex-column content not compressed when parent container height is fixed?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'm working with a simple chat box using flexbox and I want to make the chatbox scrollable and I can't figure out how can I fix the content inside the chatbox because when I set a specific height of it's parent container it will compress and does not look good.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
  // I set this container with specific height.
  .page-call-list .msg-content-wrapper{height:500px;overflow-y:visible;}

 .page-call-list .chatbox > div {flex-wrap:nowrap;}
```

It sure displays the scrollbar but the content is messed up. You can check it here http://jsfiddle.net/mrnLe509/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is to set `flex-shrink` to zero of all immediate child elements of `chatbox` by using the flex shorthand:

```
.chatbox > * {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

and then add the *overflow* to the `chatbox` instead of having it in the `msg-content-wrapper` - see demo below and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqrseog2/):

```css
.page-call-list .msg-content-wrapper {
  width: 65%;
  float: left;
  height: 500px;
  /*overflow-y: auto;*/
  position: relative;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 0px 8px 0px rgba(209, 205, 209, 0.9);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 0px 8px 0px rgba(209, 205, 209, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 8px 0px rgba(209, 205, 209, 0.9);
  height: 80px;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .timer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .timer button {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #e82b2f;
  border: solid 1px #e82b2f;
  padding: 12px 14px;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .details .name {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .details .name h2 {
  color: #1d232a;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .details a {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #009ca3;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .details a.phone:before {
  content: url(../img/call-list/phone.png);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.page-call-list .recipient-headline .details a.email:before {
  content: url(../img/call-list/email.png);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .thumbnail-wrapper.d48 {
  min-width: 48px;
}

.page-call-list .chatbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px 30px 25px;
  overflow: auto;/* ADDED */
}

.page-call-list .chatbox>div {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .recipient {
  display: flex;
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .recipient .msg {
  background: #fff;
  color: #818ca1;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 56px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .recipient .msg:after {
  right: 100%;
  top: 28px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-right-color: #fff;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .sender {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .sender .msg {
  background: #54a6de;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 56px;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 300
}

.page-call-list .chatbox .sender .msg:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 28px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(84, 166, 222, 0);
  border-left-color: #54a6de;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 80px;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner .btn {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner .btn:hover {
  background: none;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner .btn.btn-chat {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-right: solid 1px #c3c5c7;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner .btn.btn-chat img {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form .input-msg {
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #818ca1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 300
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form .input-msg::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #818ca1;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form .input-msg::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #818ca1;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form .input-msg:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #818ca1;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form .input-msg:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #818ca1;
}

.page-call-list .chat-input .chat-input--inner form #btn-send {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* ADDED THIS */
.chatbox > * {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-call-list">

  <div class="msg-content-wrapper">
    <div class="recipient-headline">
      <div class="timer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                                      -00:23 <span class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                                    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <div class="name text-right">
          <h2>Mark Zuckerberg</h2>
          <a href="tel:0123456789;" class="phone">0123 456 789</a>
          <a href="mailto:markz@gmail.com" class="email">markz@gmail.com</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chatbox">
      <div class="recipient">
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
        <div class="msg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sender">
        <div class="msg">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in.</div>
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="recipient">
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
        <div class="msg">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam volupta quia
          voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sender">
        <div class="msg">Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsumuia.</div>
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="recipient">
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
        <div class="msg">Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sender">
        <div class="msg">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in tate.</div>
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="recipient">
        <div class="thumbnail-wrapper d48 circular"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/q5qm4piu9/avatar.png"></div>
        <div class="msg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-input">
      <div class="chat-input--inner">

        <button class="btn btn-vid"><img src="https://localhost/2.0/public/assets/img/call-list/video.png" alt=""></button>
        <button class="btn btn-chat"><img src="https://localhost/2.0/public/assets/img/call-list/chat.png" alt=""></button>
        <form action="#">
          <input class="input-msg" type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type your message...">
          <button type="submit" id="btn-send"><img width="40" height="40" alt="" src="https://localhost/2.0/public/assets/img/call-list/btn-send.png"></button>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @kukkuz , got some queries regarding this, why is that the `.chatbox > div` is filling the container? How can I prevent it? https://i.imgur.com/UGhNpiv.png

Comment: sorry for the late reply... it fills because you have `flex: 1 0 100%` set on them which means that you have  `flex-grow` set to 1. Why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: because it's stretching say for example I got msg from receive with 10 words vice versa and if that number increase in a single msg then all the msgs in the chatbox that is send will have the same height.